# error on creating stored procedure in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
delimiter //
create procedure ProductGroupGenerationSettingsCheck(p_id tinyint(1),p_result varchar(50))
begin
    select automaticProductIdGeneration into p_id from tbl_Settings;
    if(p_id = 0) then
                set p_result = 'false';
    else if (p_id = 1) then
        set p_result = 'true';
    end if ;
    select p_result  as result ;
end //
delimiter ;
```

#### error

1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'begin set p_result = 'false' ; end else if (p_id = 1) begin set p_re' at line 5

Comment: use `elseif` instead of `else if`, read documentation carefully: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html as the error message sugests

Comment: It's not really clear what you hope to do with this procedure, but there are several problems with it -- the first of which is that the error message you have posted could not have been caused by *this exact* defintion, but presumably an earlier or later one you tried.